# MatExpansionModule In Angular did not render the arow

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'am a newbie in angularjs
My problem is when i work with **Expansionmodule** in **Angular Material** all the content are rendered on brower but an arrow doesn't work 
My Code:
(html file)

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel >
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            {{newPost}}
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <p> Helo_expan</p>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

(.ts file)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector:'app-post-list',
    templateUrl:'./post-list.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./post-list.component.css']
})

export class PostListComponent {
    newPost="Hellooooo";
}
```

(app.module file) I've already import {ExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion'

Below is what it rendered on browser

Can you help me find my mistake?? Thanks

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCFaq.png)

Comment: Remove the last chevron `</mat-accordion>>`. You must write `</mat-accordion>`

Comment: please mention/confirm your Angular version and dependencies.

Comment: @Emilien Thanks but it still not expand

Comment: @ThierryFalvo all of package are the lastest version. Material ver 9.1.1/Angular ver 9.0.5

Comment: answer added with stackblitz demo. any error in Chrome Dev Console ? please share it if yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to help without complete code, maybe you should have to fix something inside your configuration or imports.

No obvious error in the code snippets you shared.

Please check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60615347matexpansionmodule-in-angular-did-not-render-the-aro) as an example.

Check that correct `theme` is setup (either `angular.json` in `styles` settings, or in global `styles.css`).

You can start from this **stackblitz** example, and try to run it on your local dev environment.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what problem with angular but after deleting all the code in html and rewrite it, it's work!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what problem with angular but after deleting all the code in html file and rewrite it, it's work!!
Thanks !